# How to use <Link /> component inside dangerouslySetInnerHTML

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Currently I have this  in one of my components:

```
{someObject.map(obj => (
    <div
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
            __html: obj.text
        }}
    />
))}
```

Basically, I am mapping over `someObject` which on another file. The structure is like this:

```
export default someObject = [
      {
         obj: "<p>Some text 1.</p>"
      },
      {
         obj: "<p>Some text 2.</p>"
      }
    ]
```

I'm just simplifying the content for demonstration's sake. However, I ran into a problem because I need to use the `<Link />` component in one of the items. As in:

```
export default someObject = [
    {
        obj: "<p>Some text 1.</p>"
    },
    {
        obj: "<p>Some text 2.</p>"
    },
    {
        obj: "<p>Some text 2 and <Link to="/someroute">link</Link>.</p>"
    }
]
```

However, it's not working because that entire `<p></p>` tag is wrapped in `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

I can just use plain `<a></a>` tag for the link but that doesn't seem like a good solution as the entire application would reload instead of just going to another route.

What are the other options to make this work?

Comment: why not just convert them to simple JSX snippets and use them like regular react component children?

Comment: @Derek Can elaborate on that? Like an example?

Comment: @Derek Never mind, I got what you mean. Realised I can actually use JSX as value of the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just export the object as a jsx object? I think use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is a bad practice, it might cause XSS attack.

```js
const someObject = [
  {
    obj: <p>Some text 1.</p>
  },
  {
    obj: <p>Some text 2.<a href="https://google.com">google</a></p>
  }
]
class App extends React.Component {
  render(){ 
    return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello world</h1>
      <h2>Jsx object goes here {someObject[1].obj}</h2>
    </div>
  )};
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("container");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.2/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/15.6.2/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah I realise I can actually do that instead of wrapping everything in a string.

Answer (score 0):

- > There's is two ways to solve this problem :

## First Way :

it's like a more general approach you can use it to opt your code.
try to use this library (https://github.com/tasti/react-linkify/)

Here's the simpler form of the component  :

```js
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import Linkify from 'react-linkify';

export default class TextWithLink extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
    }

    render() {
      let text = this.props.text;
      if(this.props.showLink) {
        text = <Linkify properties={{target: '_blank', rel: "nofollow   noopener"}}>{text}</Linkify>
      }
      return (<div>{text}</div>);
    }
}
```

## Second Way :

In case, if you want to create a hyperlink (`<a>`), you should have a function which builds elements and returns the result.

Example :

```js
list = {
  text: 'hello world',
  link: 'www.facebook.com'
}
```

And the render function could be something like :

```js
buildLink() {
   return(
      <p>
        {list.text}. <a href={list.link}>{list.link}</a>
      </p>
    );
}

render() {
   return (this.buildLink());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
export default someObject = [
    {
        obj: "<p>Some text 1.</p>"
    },
    {
        obj: "<p>Some text 2.</p>"
    },
    {
        obj: linkto('/someroute')
    }
]
```

linkto will solve your issue.

Comment: Where do I insert the "link" text in ${linkto('/someroute') ?

Comment: Please first try with this code
```
obj: linkto('/login')
```